# How do I navigate between Usenet groups in Google groups?

Tags: google-groups, usenet

How do we use Google Groups to browse Usenet groups? Specifically, if I am looking at `comp.os.linux.networking`, how do I go up on level to `comp.os.linux`?

In the old days before Google changed the interface, the elements of an Usenet group were linked and clicking one would allow us to navigate up (see the red box below). And searching just sucks: `comp.os.linux groups` returned one result of `comp.os.linux.misc` (even though there are probably tens to hundred in that branch).

I don't think a traditional Usenet agent is a viable option anymore (like Forte's Agent). I'm not sure telco's like Verizon even offer them any longer. I could not find Verizon's news server settings when searching their site.

[image]

Comment: Don't know if this counts as an answer, but you could always manipulate the URL: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.os.linux

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way but to manipulate the URL. The part of the URL after the last `/` is the group name.

So to view the `com.os.linux` group, you would enter `http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.os.linux` in the browser's address bar.

If you're using Chrome, you could add a "search engine" that allows you to go straight to a Usenet group:

1. Right-click on the location bar
2. Click *Edit search engines*
   [image: Screenshot of the Edit search engines menu item]
3. In the window that pops up, scroll to the bottom, to find the *Add new search engine* field
4. Use a name you will recognize (e.g. `Usenet`), put `usenet` as the search keyword, and `http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/%s` as the URL (the `%s` will be replaced with the group name when used)
   [image: Screenshot of the Add search engine form]
5. From now on, you can type `usenet` in the location bar and press <kbd>tab</kbd>. Then type the name of the group you want to view (e.g. `comp.os.linux`)
   [image: Screenshot of the Chrome location bar]
6. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>. This will take you to `http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.os.linux`

Similar options exist for at least Firefox (called [Smart bookmarks](http://lifehacker.com/387944/how-to-make-your-own-smart-bookmarks-in-firefox-3)) and [Opera](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.50/en/search.html), and perhaps other browsers (feel free to add to this answer).

Comment: As of October 2023, the core of the answer is still working. **"There seems to be no way but to manipulate the URL. The part of the URL after the last / is the group name"**. The URLs on this answer are obsolete they redirected to the current URL structure.